# Using lapply function to separate columns that consist of two columns

Tags: r, time-series, lapply

I have a data like here. The data contains rainfall values for 3 years (2005-2006-2007) separately.

**Data:**

```
mydata<-structure(list(X2005.hourly = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.6, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.6, 0.2, 0.6, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0.6, 1.2, 1.8, 1.8, 
1.2, 1, 1.2, 1.6, 1.2, 1.4, 1, 1.2, 0.8, 0.8, 0.2, 0, 0, 1.6, 
0.4, 0, 0.4, 1.2, 0.8, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 1.2, 1.6, 2.2, 1.8, 0.4, 0.6, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.4, 0.2, 
0, 0, 0.8, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0, 0, 1.2, 4, 
0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.6, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 1.4, 0.6, 0.4, 0.8, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 1.2, 
1, 1.8, 2, 1.8, 0.4, 0.6, 1.2, 1.8, 1.4, 1.2, 0.6, 0.4, 0, 0.2, 
0.2, 1.6, 1.6, 1.4, 0.8, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0, 0.6, 0, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 1.6, 1.8, 
1.2, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 0.6, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2006.hourly = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4.8, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6.6, 0.2, 0, 0, 
0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 1.4, 0, 1.2, 0, 0.2, 0, 0.2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.2, 1.8, 2, 2.2, 0.6, 0.8, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 1.8, 5.8, 0.2, 0.4, 0, 3.8, 0.2, 1.2, 0.4, 0, 
0, 1, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.6, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.8, 0.8, 1, 0.2, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.6, 2.4, 
0.2, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 1.6, 0.2, 2, 0, 1.2, 4.6, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.8, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.2, 1.8, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0.4, 2, 1, 0.8, 0.4, 0.2, 0, 0.2, 0, 
0.8, 0.8, 0.2, 0.2, 0, 0.4, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 4, 2, 0.8, 2.6, 1.4, 
0.6, 1, 1, 1, 1.2, 1.2, 0.8, 1.6, 1.8, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.6, 1.2, 0.6, 0.8, 
0.8, 1, 0.8, 1.2, 1.2, 0.8, 1, 2.2, 3.4, 2.6, 1.8, 1.6, 1.8, 
3.6, 3, 1.8, 3.2, 1.8, 1, 0.6, 0.4, 0, 1, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.6, 3.8, 0.2, 0.4, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.6, 0, 0.6, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.6, 0.4, 0.6, 0.4, 0.6, 1, 0.8, 0.2, 0, 0, 
0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.2, 0.6, 1.4, 2.2, 0, 0.4, 1, 0.6, 0, 1.2, 1.6, 0.6, 0, 
0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.4, 0.2, 0, 1.2, 0.4, 1, 0.6, 0.8, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), X2007.hourly = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.6, 0.4, 1, 2.2, 2.6, 1.8, 0.8, 0.6, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.4, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.6, 0.4, 0.4, 0.6, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 
0.4, 0, 1.4, 0.4, 0.8, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.6, 0.6, 0.4, 
0.6, 0.8, 1, 0.8, 1.4, 1.4, 2.2, 0.8, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.6, 
0.6, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.4, 0.6, 1, 
1, 0.6, 1.4, 1.4, 0.6, 0.4, 0.6, 0.6, 0.8, 1, 1.8, 1.6, 0.6, 
0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.4, 0.8, 1.6, 1.8, 1.6, 
1, 1, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.4, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.2, 0, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.8, 0.2, 0, 1, 0.2, 0.6, 1.6, 1, 0.6, 
0.6, 0.4, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.6, 1.4, 0.2, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 2.4, 1.2, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.6, 3, 1.4, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.6, 0.2, 2.6, 3, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.8, 0.2, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.2, 0, 0.2, 0, 0.4, 0.4, 0.8, 0.8, 1.2, 1, 0.6, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2, 
0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.8, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0.2, 
0, 0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("X2005.hourly", "X2006.hourly", 
"X2007.hourly"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -744L))
```

**And the function I used before:**

```
    myfun<- function(x) {
      y<-as.matrix(sapply(x, as.numeric)) 
#Aggregating hourly data to 6,12 and 24 hourly data      
h<-sapply(c(1, 6, 12, 24), function(hrs) colSums(matrix(y, ncol=length(x)/hrs)))
      hours<-sapply(list(h[[1]], h[[2]], h[[3]], h[[4]]), function(qq) list(qq))
      names(hours)<-c("hourly", "h.6", "h.12", "h.24")
#Calculating means of 1, 6, 12 and 24 hourly data      
means<-sapply(list(hours[[1]], hours[[2]], hours[[3]], hours[[4]]), function(ss) mean(ss, na.rm = T))
    #means of 1, 6, 12 and 24 hourly data 
      mean1<-means[[1]]
      mean6<-means[[2]]
      mean12<-means[[3]]
      mean24<-means[[4]]
      meanlist<-list(mean1, mean6, mean12, mean24)
      names(meanlist) <- c("mean1", "mean6", "mean12", "mean24")
      return(meanlist)
    }
```

**What I did:** 
I am applying `myfun` with `lapply` function and I am getting results separately for each year. And there is no trouble here.

```
results<-lapply(mydata, myfun)
```

**What I want:**

As you see, there is `h.24` term inside of `names(hours)` in the `myfun` function . To calculate mean of `24 hourly data`, function is using `h.24` data aggregated  from `hourly` data. But I want to use external 24 hourly `daily` data instead of `h.24`. In the data below, there are `daily` values separately for `2005,2006,2007`

```
adddata<-structure(list(X2005.daily = c(0, 0, 3.4, 21.4, 1.8, 1.4, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8.6, 1.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.6, 7, 6.4, 21.8, 
3.2, 0, 0, 0.6, 11.2, 0), X2006.daily = c(0, 8.6, 11.2, 8.4, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7.8, 7.6, 1.2, 10.2, 7, 0, 0, 1.6, 7.6, 23.6, 
3.2, 0, 9, 31.4, 10, 2.2, 1.6, 0, 4.8, 10, 1.2, 4.6), X2007.daily = c(0.6, 
9.4, 4.2, 7.2, 15, 15, 0.4, 0, 8.6, 0, 0.2, 0.8, 0, 0.6, 0.6, 
1.4, 8.2, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 1.6, 4, 5.2, 0, 0, 7, 4.2, 7.2)), .Names = c("X2005.daily", 
"X2006.daily", "X2007.daily"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-31L))
```

**Briefly:** I want to add external `daily` data for each year, and then I want to calculate means of 1, 6, 12 hourly values and also means of added `daily` data for each year. So, the results of `mean1, mean6, mean12` will be the same but `mean24` will be the mean of added daily values.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, this should work:

```
results <- do.call(cbind,results) #convert your list to a data.frame for better overview
colnames(results) <- c("X2005","X2006","X2007")
results <- rbind(results,meanDaily=colMeans(adddata)) #rbind the colMeans of you adddata

results

          X2005        X2006        X2007
mean1     0.1193548    0.2336022    0.1430108   
mean6     0.716129     1.401613     0.8580645   
mean12    1.432258     2.803226     1.716129    
mean24    2.864516     5.606452     3.432258 
meanDaily 2.864516     5.574194     3.43871
```

---

Additional answer to request in comment:

```
library(zoo)

myfun <- function(df_hourly,df_daily)
{

  DF <- sapply(df_hourly,function(col){c(mean(rollapply(col,width=1,sum,by=1,align="left")),
                                mean(rollapply(col,width=6,sum,by=6,align="left")),
                                mean(rollapply(col,width=12,sum,by=12,align="left")),
                                mean(rollapply(col,width=24,sum,by=24,align="left")))})
  DF <- rbind(DF,colMeans(adddata))

  colnames(DF) <- c("yr2005","yr2006","yr2007")
  rownames(DF) <- c("mean.1hr","mean.6hr","mean.12hr","mean.24hr","mean.daily")
  return(DF)
}


myfun(mydata,adddata)

              yr2005    yr2006    yr2007
mean.1hr   0.1193548 0.2336022 0.1430108
mean.6hr   0.7161290 1.4016129 0.8580645
mean.12hr  1.4322581 2.8032258 1.7161290
mean.24hr  2.8645161 5.6064516 3.4322581
mean.daily 2.8645161 5.5741935 3.4387097
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But after finding `mean`, I need to find variance, autocovariance etc. So I guess, I need solution not only for mean, but also for another values.

Comment: Then just use the appropiate function instead of `colMeans`

Comment: One more question, what if I want to use these codes in function? I mean for these codes, I need to find results and then add `meanDaily` to `results`. But I want to obtain it without finding result?

Comment: I added a solution for your problem combined with a much easier computation of the rolling means using `zoo`

Comment: I am sorry for repeater questions. But how can I use the new code in `lapply` loop? For example, I will import almost 680 different `hourly` and `daily`data. Each data is consisting hourly and daily columns.

Comment: well just lapply over your datasets. If you are not able to do this, please ask a new question to your specific problem and provide a reproducible example for this